# how can i make grep/find/locate beep as it finds each match

Tags: command-line, audio, file-search

I am looking for files, since I added a backup external HD. I want to continue working elsewhere, while find/grep/locate find a file. As a match is found, I'd like to be alerted so that i can stop the search, in case it was the one i intended to find.

Can there be an audible alert per match?

Comment: Well, at least with GNU `find`, there's a `\a` (terminal bell) escape char - so you could do something like `find . -name foo -printf '\a' -print`. Is that the kind of thing you want?

Comment: yes! exactly. thanks (should you write it as answer to close the quesion?)

Comment: Thanks - I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with GNU find, the `-printf` action supports a `\a` (terminal bell) escape char - so at its simplest you could do something like

```
find . -name foo -printf '\a' -print
```

I'm not aware of an equivalent with `grep` or `locate`.